# How to use a custom Oracle sequence for Django Model PK?

Tags: django, oracle, orm, primary-key

I'am integrating Django with a table inside an existing Oracle database, which has a sequence already created and its PK (Numeric) defined. What I want to achieve is to be able to create new rows for this table using the currently defined sequence. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/haoch/4000035/), changed the id to pk notation so that it can be used generically:

```
# your_app/models.py

def update_pk(func):
'''A decorator for pulling a data objects PK value out of a
   user-defined sequence.  This gets around a limitation in 
   django whereby we cannot supply our own sequence names.'''

    def decorated_function(*args):
        # Grab a reference to the data object we want to update.
        data_object = args[0]

        # Only update the PK if there isnt one yet.
        if data_object.pk is None:
            # Construct the new sequence name based on the tables meta data. This might be different depending on your needs
            sequence_name = 'seq_%s' % data_object._meta.db_table

            # Query the database for the next sequence value.
            from django.db import connection
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT %s.nextval FROM DUAL;" % (sequence_name))
            row = cursor.fetchone()

            # Update the data objects PK with the returned sequence value.
            data_object.pk = row[0]

         # Execute the function were decorating.
         return func(*args)

    return decorated_function


# Example model using the decorator to grab the PK.
class FAQ(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(FAQCategory)
    question = models.CharField(maxlength=255)
    answer = models.TextField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    list_ordering = models.FloatField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=9999)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    @update_pk
    def save(self):
        # Now actually save the object.
        super(FAQ, self).save()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'faqs'
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this last week.  My table is defined with `managed = false` in Meta, and an Oracle sequence is used to provide the primary key value.  To tell Django to get the key value after the row is saved, declare the column as an AutoField:

```
surrogate_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: How do you declare the sequence to use to populate the field?

Comment: Adam, using a Django managed table, the framework will create and link the required sequence in Oracle. No need to code separately.  My suggestion was meant only for use with unmanaged tables that already have a sequence setup.

Comment: My question was more "With an unmanaged table, how do you generate new sequence values and get them in."  

So far, I've seen people using insert triggers to update the column from the sequence, but I was hoping to see some better way inside of django.

Comment: Oh, so you're adding the ID and sequence to the existing table.  That's a little out of my experience.